# Using regex to strip off from a large string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to extract from string a pattern of characters and use the string as filenames

Problem:
The string in question is

Algoxasx (AGC)Tomcat Empty Mind (BAA)BIG Fat (BGI)Big King Location (BAU)MEP Ezay (EYI)East Borderline (EYUS)Sasha Banks (ME)Grand Canyon (GCP) ....

Background:
The above string is got by using Beautiful Soup to parse website along with Python-which is an easier part by using class and attributes and html parser.Forgive me ,The code cant be posted in entirety as it is a research project of my school that holds the copyright for the code

Objective:
I want to strip off from the above string (AGC),(BGI),(BAU),(EYI).... and extract only only Algoxasx Tomcat BIG Fat Big King Locattion etc. I want to later use these extracted names in a separate manner like say eg if a file is downloaded use them as a filename to store the file.

What I Tried until now :
 I used regex to strip above (AGC),(BAA),(BGI) as a list and used both replace method (replace with empty space) and strip method along with regex to extract the string without paranthesis containing the capital letters .I also tried using split method but it splits individual letters rather than words

```
 data1=required_data.find(class_='dropdown-menu select-pipe-dropdown- 
 menu',attrs={'id':'dropdown'}).get_text
 r2=re.findall(r'\([^\)]*[A-Z]{2}[^\)]*\)',data1)
 w=data1.replace(r2,'')
 print(w)
```

The data1 method contains the entire string  Algoxasx (AGC)Tomcat Empty Mind (BAA)BIG Fat (BGI)Big King Location (BAU)MEP Ezay (EYI)East Borderline (EYUS)Sasha Banks (ME)Grand Canyon (GCP)

The r2 variable extracts (AGC),(BGI),(BAU),(EYI) as a list

Expected Result 1 :
Algoxasx Tomcat Empty Mind BIG Fat Big King Location MEP Ezay East Borderline Sasha Banks Grand Canyon

Expected Result 2 :
Separate above string individually so that I can use them separately in a for loop eg Algoxasx, Tomcat Empty Mind, BIG Fat, Big King Location, MEP Ezay East Borderline, Sasha Banks, Grand Canyon

Answer (score 0):

With `re.split()` you could split the string according regex rules:

```
s = '''
Algoxasx (AGC)Tomcat Empty Mind (BAA)BIG Fat (BGI)Big King Location (BAU)MEP Ezay (EYI)East Borderline (EYUS)Sasha Banks (ME)Grand Canyon (GCP)
'''

import re
from pprint import pprint

data = [d.strip() for d in re.split(r'\([A-Z]{2,}\)', s) if d.strip()]
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
['Algoxasx',
 'Tomcat Empty Mind',
 'BIG Fat',
 'Big King Location',
 'MEP Ezay',
 'East Borderline',
 'Sasha Banks',
 'Grand Canyon']
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for that. What is pprint and why is it needed?

Comment: @Akshay `pprint` stands for pretty printing. You could use standard `print`. Here it is only for printing values in nice column.